# Original Fraïssé's paper and texts on Fraïssé theory

Tags: logic, reference-request, model-theory

I wonder where I can find the Fraïssé's paper "Sur l’extension aux  relations  de quelques propriet es  desordres", appeared in  Annales  Scientifiques  de l'Ecole  Normale Superieure. Troisieme Śerie 71 (1954), 363–388." (or an English translation).

Also I'd like to know which text on model theory discuss details on Fraïssé theory, with one main result being a countable homogeneous structure is completely determined by its age.

Comment: My first reference was Hodges "A Shorter Model Theory", chapter 6

Comment: A simple Google search for "Sur l’extension aux relations de quelques propriet es desordres" turned up this page as the first result: https://eudml.org/doc/81696. It contains a pdf of the paper (in French).

Comment: Also available the two volumes Roland Fraïssé, [Course of Mathematical Logic. Volume 1: Relation and Logical Formula & Volume 2: Model Theory (Springer, 1973)](https://books.google.it/books?id=7sLrCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure about an English translation of that particular paper, but Fraïssé's book *Theory of Relations* is available in English translation (this includes what is today called Fraïssé theory, in Section 11.1).

I agree with HallaSurvivor's comment that Hodges' *A Shorter Model Theory* is the best textbook reference for Fraïssé theory.

Comment: @hermes More general? No, just different. Direct limit is a construction you do to a chain of structures. Fraïssé limit is a construction you do to a Fraïssé class of finite structures (which are not canonically arranged in a chain). The direct limit produces the "smallest" structure containing the chain (in the sense of its universal property), while the Fraïssé limit produces the "richest" countable structure containing all the structures in the class (in the sense of homogeneity).

Comment: The direct limit construction occurs all the time in model theory. One place it appears is in the construction of Fraïssé limits: the proof goes by cleverly constructing a chain of structures from the class (which witnesses all possible extensions in a precise sense) and then taking the direct limit of the chain.

Comment: @hermes Literally any book which covers Fraïssé limits. It's the standard proof (though many authors will write "union" instead of "direct limit", because the direct limit along a chain of inclusion maps is just the union). Again, Hodges is a good choice.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I don't think your comment about direct limits is quite right: we can take the direct limit of an arbitrary countable family of structures/homomorphisms which is appropriately "directed and commutative," and we can construe the Fraisse limit as such.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I'm not sure I understand your comment. Which part are you saying is not quite right?

Comment: @AlexKruckman "More general? No, just different. Direct limit is a construction you do to a chain of structures. Fraïssé limit is a construction you do to a Fraïssé class of finite structures." A direct limit need not be done to a chain, and Fraisse limits are really just special cases of direct limits. (That said, of course this is an incredibly minor nitpick.) EDIT: actually, I suppose the effort of properly setting up a Fraisse limit as literally a direct limit makes that a somewhat silly thing to do.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ah, sure - you're pointing out that the Fraïssé limit can be viewed as a directed colimit, rather than the direct limit of a chain. This is true, in a somewhat trivial sense: *every* structure is a directed colimit of its finitely generated substructures. But I  disagree that the Fraïssé limit *construction* is a special case of the directed colimit *construction*. The reason is that the input data is different. The input to the Fraïssé limit is a Fraïssé class, while the input to the directed colimit is a particular diagram.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Fair (and see my edit to my previous comment). But I don't understand where *co*limits are coming in - isn't everything here just a direct limit?

Comment: (continued) The directed colimit has a "mapping out" universal property with respect to this diagram. The Fraïssé limit has no such "mapping out" universal property with respect to the Fraïssé class. To construe the Fraïssé limit as a directed colimit, one needs to carefully put together an appropriate diagram from the Fraïssé cass.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Oh - there's this annoyance that in the classical terminology, "direct limits" are certain kinds of colimits (the directed ones), while "inverse limits" are certain kinds of limits (the codirected ones!). I just switched from "direct limit" to "directed colimit" to emphasize that I was not longer restricting to direct limits along a chain.

Comment: @AlexKruckman "Oh - there's this annoyance that in the classical terminology, "direct limits" are certain kinds of colimits, while "inverse limits" are certain kinds of limits." **OH GODDAMMIT**. :P Thanks!